# Joining Data from Two Datasets

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataset

All I really want to do is a join. Table 1 and Table 2 both have a number that would link the two together. I want to join two fields from Table 2 onto Table 1. I need to have two datasets because there are two different connections being made.

I want to push this onto a DataGridView, which only allows a single datasource. So I'm thinking I would need to make a temp table somehow, but since I'm pulling from two different datasets I don't know if that's possible.

I saw this: [Combine multiple dataset columns to one dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868335/combine-multiple-dataset-columns-to-one-dataset) but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Just because there are two different connections doesn't mean you can't put tables / views from the different connections into the same dataset.  Your DataAdapters will just have different connection strings in your app.config file.

Answer (score 3):

If the tables have the same or nearly the same schema, you can use the Merge method on the DataSet:

```
dataset1.Merge(dataset2, True, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
dataset1.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: This would work except the primary keys aren't the same in each DataSet.

Comment: If you have a common field between the two tables, have you tried redefining the primary key within the table to be that common field?

Comment: Yeah. The issue is that one is a string type and one is an integer. I changed this but I was getting constraint issues. It's really convoluted the way they did this (this database is at least 7 years old). I was importing this into Excel anyways, so via the Excel Interop COM I put a column which has the vlookup function and it's working. Obviously not the best solution but it works.